# How can I make the up arrow work in Terminal's nslookup command?

Tags: terminal, dns

When I open terminal, I'd like the up arrow go to the last command I typed within `nslookup`. Instead, I get a strange escape sequence.

What must be done to allow me to up arrow in nslookup?

Comment: It is the default behaviour to get your last entered command when you press up arrow. You must've gotten something messed up.

Comment: @Alex You're right, but I seemed to just notice this within an interactive `nslookup`.  I just revised the question.

Comment: The default "read an inputline from the user" under Unix does not support arrow keys.  It is an extra library which needs to be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nslookup on OS X does not seem to use readline, so it does not support the arrow keys.

You can install [rlwrap](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/uck/rlwrap/), which is available in [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org) and presumably other package managers.  Then you can run

```
rlwrap nslookup
```

To get arrow key support.

Many thanks to [this thread](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1091585) on the MacRumors forums.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using bash someones changed your key bindings. Look at ~/.bash_profile and see what's in there. Alternatively go to the Preferences for Terminal and select the profile you are using and then click on the Keyboard Tab. See if the cursor up is set to anything weird there.

As someone else mentioned the default setting in Terminal and bash is to display the last command.